# Is the product P = B^T * B positive-definite if B is a square matrix?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I am looking for a matrix parametrization that guarantees positive definiteness. The target matrix P shall be positive-definite. I thought about writing P = B^T * B, where B is some square matrix. Then, for any choice of B, is the result P positive-definite? I am not quite sure.

Thanks!

Best, JZ

Comment: $ \langle Px, x \rangle=\|Bx\|^{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: For any choice of $B$? How that? Just consider $B=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Positive definite often means non-negative definite.

Comment: When $B$ is a real square matrix, $B^TB$ is positive definite if and only if $B$ is nonsingular.

Comment: ok, for pd nonsingular real square matrix, for psd any real square matrix, if i do understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, assuming that you are talking about real square matrices. For complex square matrices, the analogous holds if you consider $B^\ast B$.